# HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, hosting

I have published my website to hosting but i got the problem "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" and my website shows "Error. An error occurred while processing your request"
I turned off customError mode and this is what it shows

> Server Error in '/' Application. Invalid URI: The format of the URI
> could not be determined. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
> during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
> stack trace for more information about the error and where it
> originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format
> of the URI could not be determined.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace: `[UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.]    System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) +8516254    System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString) +44    CheckWebsite.Controllers.HomeController.WebRequestTest(String url) in D:\Projects\CheckWebsite\CheckWebsite\Controllers\HomeController.cs:111 CheckWebsite.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in D:\Projects\CheckWebsite\CheckWebsite\Controllers\HomeController.cs:26 lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
> parameters) +35
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +69    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +80    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +387    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +69    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59    System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +73
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38    System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +40    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +73
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> +38    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +602    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128`

And I checked the server log and it says "500 GET / - HTTP/2"

How can I resolve this situation and get the website up and running?

My website works good when I try it on localhost but for some reason it can't run on the server.
I've seen some articles but I can't apply it.

And this is my code:

```
public static bool WebRequestTest(string url)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest myRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
  List<QLWebsite> obj = strDM.getDomain(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
  {
    if (WebRequestTest(obj[i].Domain) == false)
    {
      obj[i].status = false;
      strDM.EditDomain(obj[i]);  
    }
    else
    {
      obj[i].status = true;
      strDM.EditDomain(obj[i]);
    }
  }
  return View(obj);
}
```

Comment: The stack trace tells us that the error is occurring in your `HomeController` class. Please show us that class, particularly the `WebRequestTest(String url)` and `Index() methods.

Comment: @sbridewell I apologize for not inserting the code snippet in the previous post. I added that code to my post. Thanks!

Comment: So one (or more) of the `QLWebsite` instances in the list returned by the `getDomain` method has a `Domain` property which is in the wrong format to be a URL. If localhost and the web server are giving you different results then it's probably something environmental. Your best bet is to add some [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line) to the `getDomain` method and compare the logs from localhost and from the web server to understand what is behaving differently in the population of the `Domain` property.

Comment: The logging link in my previous comment applies to .net full framework. If you're using .net core or .net 5 or higher, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 instead